# java selenium check if modal popup present

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am having trouble dealing with modal popup windows in selenium (webdriver java).

```
public void setScoring() {
    try {
        Set<String> popUp = driver.getWindowHandles();
        Iterator<String> it = popUp.iterator();
        String parent = it.next();
        String child = it.next();
        driver.switchTo().window(child);
        driver.findElement(By.id("button0")).click();
        driver.switchTo().window(parent);
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) { }
}
```

I need to run this code only if a popup is present (let say every third run), but this code does not work.

Comment: I believe I had to execute javascript on some of these as it was an actual "alert" and not a window.  That gets tied to the browser as an alert and not the window node structure as you are attempting.  Can you confirm exactly what the popup is rendered as (in browser reference)?

Comment: it's not an alert. I have to use getWindowHandles() to switch bettwen them. I've tried `Alert alert = webDriver.switchTo().alert();` not work. I need to check if popup exist if yes then run this code if not continue to another step.

Comment: can you post the html?  I assume your "parent" and "child" are the session id's of the two windows?  I'm also confused as it sounds like you can find the popup via the session...correct?

Comment: I can't I'm not in job right now... but I know how to handle windows... in another step is working well, but this one shows time to time. How I wrote, my problem is that I can't find the way how to check if this popup is present.

Comment: ok, so something is different about this popup than the other ones.  It's hard to say without being able to see the difference between the two in html or some other programmatic way.  My suggestion would be to try and interact with it via dev tools, firebug, javascript, etc... and see you can find any differences in the popup itself from the other popups.  Perhaps it's called differently than the other popups and you can see the code call difference?

Comment: Hi... I figured out my self. Problem was that on the whole site after click has been transformed to the frame... now everything working well...

Comment: Could you add what worked for you as an answer then?